# How can I save my emails via "print as PDF". What tool can I use?

Tags: pdf, email, thunderbird

I have to save my emails as an offline file to put it on a USB stick or what ever.
I want to save it as a PDF.
When I marked a couple of emails in THUNDERBIRD. and then go on "print as file" it makes just the 1st email to a PDF. How can I do more( thousands)?
Thanks for your help
vanessa

PS: I am no computer specialist. I need is as simple as possible!

can no one help me??

Comment: @sudodus This is not an answer to the OP's question. The request is to print e-mails to PDF, not to migrate them to another computer.

Comment: @sudodus But they don't help to solve the OP's problem...

Comment: @VanessaLinda. Please explain how you intend to use the emails. Would it be an option to copy the files containing the settings and the email contents and run Thunderbird offline?

Comment: I want to save the emails on an external harddrive to have access to them in case we want to see the emails again. I have to be able to see the emails WITHOUT thunderbird.

Comment: Can someone HELP E PLEASE??

Comment: @VanessaLinda, You can use a USB stick with a persistent live Ubuntu system (with Thunderbird and the files containing the emails and the settings of Thunderbird) or if you would rather have an installed Ubuntu system (installed in a portable way in the USB stick, it would also work). - This is not exactly what you ask for but it should work as a way to make the emails portable (at least between PC computers). - I can give you links describing ways to create such systems if you are interested, but I don't know how to make exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 4):

You're right: A stock install of Thunderbird seems to convert only the first selected email to PDF, regardless of how many are selected. This seems arguably a bug -- feel free to report the issue to the Thunderbird developers.

Several add-ons are available that add the functionality.

Go to to top menu, select Tools --> Add-ons and Themes. Several add-ons are available that promise batch PDF export. Search for "PDF Export" for a list of them.

[image]

Comment: I couldnt find something that works.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want **Print** for that task, but rather **Save selected messages** provided by the addon [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/?src=search)(*needs to be installed first*) ...

[image]